# How to calculate age and sex-adjusted z-scores in SPSS

Tags: spss, standardization, age

I have a large data set in SPSS which includes triceps skinfold measurements for children at various ages. I would like to create z-scores for these measurements which adjust for sex and age... is there a way of creating internal z-scores in SPSS which will adjust for these things?

Comment: If you mean - to compute z-scores separately for subgroups, then use Split file by the subgroups and then use Descriptives procedure to compute z-scores.

Comment: Thank you -that would work to adjust for sex I think. Do you know of any way to also adjust for age? E.g. measurements were supposedly taken at 6 months of age, but some children were 6.3 month old and some were 5.9 months old etc. ?

Comment: Then - if age is a continuous variable - it is unclear what you mean saying "adjust for age". Please clarify that. May it be about a regression issue?

Comment: So I could create z-scores for birth weight by splitting the file between sexes. However, each child has a different gestation period before birth which would affect their birth weight. Maybe to get around this I could use gestation as a covariate in ANOVAs?

Comment: I think that you may be right thinking of ANCOVA

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185395/how-can-i-calculate-age-adjusted-z-score/240668#240668) but since I can't comment yet I repost my answer (adjusted your example) here as well.

Most likely the easiest way to adjust one variable for the effect of an other variable is computing standardized residuals from a simple regression. Typically I use this when dealing with reaction time data and adjusting for eg. the effect of answers extremity.

Considering age is continuous, sex is coded as dummy variable then 
if `y` is your dependent variable, run simple regression for `y= b0 + age + sex`

In SPSS a ZRE_1 variable will be computed once you tick `standardized residuals` in SAVE menu before running a Linear Regression.

In R you could compute it by running:

```
adjusted.dv<- rstandard(lm (dv ~ age + sex))
```