# how can I calculate age-adjusted z score?

Tags: spss, z-score, age

I'd like to know if there's a way to calculate z-score adjusted for age in SPSS.
then, I want to use age-adjusted z-score as a dependent variable in path analysis.

Comment: 'How to do ______ in SPSS?' questions are off topic here. However it's possible we could be of help, can you say more about your situation, your data, & your model? There may be a better way to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the easiest way to adjust one variable for the effect of an other variable is computing standardized residuals from a simple regression. Typically I use this when dealing with reaction time data and adjusting for e.g. the effect of answers extremity.

If `y` is your dependent variable, run simple regression for `y= b0 + age`

In SPSS you'd go to `SAVE` option in `Regression -> Linear`

While in R you could compute it by running:

```
adjusted.dv<- rstandard(lm (dv ~ age))
```